# How avoid 404 when using history API HTML5

Tags: javascript, ember.js, senna.js

In [SennaJS](http://sennajs.com/) and EmberJS both using History API.
How those libraries avoid 404 when a URL is pasted in address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your webserver and enable mod_rewrite. Then the server will take the request and forward it to your index file, and ember and SennaJS will parse the URL as you would expect.

For Apache you need to enable mod rewrite and edit your vhost:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

and nginx:

```
rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
```

see: http://readystate4.com/2012/05/17/nginx-and-apache-rewrite-to-support-html5-pushstate/

Comment: But how Ember do this local?